# Best way to handle multiple container transactions operations in Cosmosdb Nosql?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi, azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi

Currently I am trying to design an application where we have a CosmosDB account representing a group of customers with:

- One container is used an overall Metadata store that contains all customers
- Other containers will containers will contain data specific to one customer where data will be partitioned on according to different categories of customer history etc.

When we onboard a new customer (which will not happen too often and once) we'd like to make sure that we create an row in the Overall customer Metadata and then provision the customer specific container if fail rollback the transaction if it fails. (In the future we'd like to remove customers as well.)

Unfortunately the Cosmosdb Nosql only supports transactions in one container within the same logical partition, and does not support multi-container transactions. Our own POC indicates the MongoDB api does support this but unfortunately MongoDB does not fit our use case as we need support for Azure Functions.

Answer (score 1):

The heart of the problem here isn't whether Cosmos DB supports distributed transactions. The core problem is you can't enlist an Azure Control Plane action (in this case, creating a container resource) into a transaction.

Since you're building in the cloud, my recommendation would be to employ the outbox pattern to manage your provisioning state for your customers. There's an easy to understand example [here](https://madeofstrings.com/2022/10/25/transactional-outbox-pattern-with-azure-functions-and-cosmos-db/) you can read.

Given you are building a multi-tenant application for Cosmos DB and using containers as your tenant boundary, please note that the maximum number of databases and/or containers in an account is 500. Please see [Service Quotas](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/concepts-limits) for more information.